# How does bmesh apply transforms?

Tags: scripting

Apply move, rotate, scale transforms.
I don't want to change the state of the original object, so I can't use bpy.ops.object.transform_apply

```py
# The full script, the preceding part can be ignored
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils
import bmesh, time
from mathutils import Vector, bvhtree, Matrix
from math import radians, floor, degrees

def get_view_regions(context):
    screen = context.screen
    view_region = None
    view_region_3d = None
    for a in screen.areas:
       if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
            view_region_3d = a.spaces[0].region_3d
            for reg in a.regions[:]:
                if reg.type == "WINDOW":
                    view_region = reg
                    break
            break
    return view_region, view_region_3d

def get_screen_normal(region, rv3d, coord):
    return view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(
            region, rv3d, coord)   

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Please see the following code
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

def visible_face_1(i, n, m, d):
    r = degrees( d.angle(n) )
    if r > 90.5:
        return i
    return -1

def visible_face_2(i, n, m, d):
    n = n.to_4d()
    n.w = 0
    n = (m @ n).to_3d()
    r = degrees( d.angle(n) )
    if r > 90.5:
        return i
    return -1

region, rv3d = get_view_regions(C)

obj = bpy.context.active_object  
me = obj.data 
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bvh = bvhtree.BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm)


screen_normal = get_screen_normal(region, rv3d, 
            (region.width // 2, region.height // 2))

matrix_local = obj.matrix_local.inverted()
o = matrix_local @ Vector((0,0,0))
data = bvh.find_nearest_range(o, 1)
matrix = obj.matrix_world

start = time.time()

rs_1 = set([visible_face_1(item[2], item[1], matrix, screen_normal) for item in data])

end_1 = time.time()

rs_2 = set([visible_face_2(item[2], item[1], matrix, screen_normal) for item in data])

end_2 = time.time()

print(end_1 - start, end_2 - end_1) # 0.15470099449157715 0.2967987060546875
```

visible_face_1 is twice as fast as visible_face_2, the time loss of

```py
# If the object has transformations such as scaling, the normal cannot be obtained accurately
# so the following code is required
n = n.to_4d()
n.w = 0
n = (m @ n).to_3d()
```

is huge.

So if you can apply the transformation in bmesh, you can avoid wasting.

> bmesh only needs to be executed once, find_nearest_range runs frequently

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

---

## The solution:

```py
matrix = obj.matrix_world
bmesh.ops.transform(bm, matrix=matrix, verts=bm.verts)
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the inverse matrix of the object to the vertices and applying the matrix afterwards ? Transforms are an object level concept, vertices are only aware of the object local origin, they are translated, rotated and scaled afterwards

Comment: @Gorgious I have too little experience in graphics, and I don’t know how to use matrices.  I think it’s easier to make a copy of the object and apply the transformation, but to be honest, I don’t want to do it. Graphics give me a headache……

Comment: Hehe so my advice is either you accept to use suboptimal solutions or you need to take some time to learn how to use matrices :)

Comment: @Gorgious I found a way, thanks for the reminder